# Using grunt plugins

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, workflow

I have following gruntfile

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {



    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        htmlhint: {
            build: {
                options: {
                    'tag-pair': true,
                    'tagname-lowercase': true,
                    'attr-lowercase': true,
                    'attr-value-double-quotes': true,
                    'doctype-first': true,
                    'spec-char-escape': true,
                    'id-unique': true,
                    'head-script-disabled': true,
                    'style-disabled': true
                },
                src: ['index.html']
            }
        },
        watch: {
            html: {
                files: ['index.html'],
                tasks: ['htmlhint']
            }
        }
    });

    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);



};
```

And when i try running `grunt` in cmd it gives me this error

> Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

How do i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `htmlhint` task to the default:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlhint', 'watch']);
```

Also make sure you have installed `grunt-htmlhint` and saved it to your `package.json`. `matchdep` uses it in the `filterDev` method you're using, so if its not saved, it won't get loaded.

```
npm install grunt-htmlhint --save-dev
```

Alternatively you could load the task manually using:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-htmlhint');
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie.  It show a warning as `Warning: Task "htmlhint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.`

Comment: maybe you're also missing `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-htmlhint');`? - although i guess the `forEach` should cover that

Comment: have you run `npm install grunt-htmlhint --save-dev` ?

Comment: I am using `matchdep`  to include dependency list by running `require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);'` which caused the problem.. i dont know the reason :( . but wow... i included dependencies separately as grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-htmlhint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch'); it worked. Thanks

Comment: no worries, make sure you use `--save-dev` when you install grunt tasks with npm, or your `matchdep.filterDev` won't find the module